# simple shell wont go to new line when ENTER is pressed

Tags: c

working on making a simple shell, minor issue now is when i press enter on a blank line the program fails (segmentation fault). but when i take out the '\n' in the delim string it works fine but then command executions do not work.

```
($) 
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

instead of this:

```
($) 
($)
```

this is my code:

```
void get_cmd(char **userinput)
{
        size_t r = 1000;

        getline(userinput, &r, stdin);
}

char **split_str(char *buf)
{
        char *token, **eachstr, *delim = " \n";
        int count = 0;

        eachstr = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
        if (!eachstr)
                return (NULL);

        token = strtok(buf, delim);
        while (token)
         {
                eachstr[count] = token;
                token = strtok(NULL, delim);

                count++;
        }
        eachstr[count] = NULL;

        return (eachstr);

}

int main(void)
{
        unsigned int status = 1;
        char *userinput, **args;

        userinput = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000);
        if (!userinput)
        {
                perror("cant allocate memory");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        while (status)
        {

                _print("($) ");
                get_cmd(&userinput);
                args = split_str(userinput);

                if (_strcmp(args[0], "exit") == 0)
                        status = 0;
                execute(args);
             free(args);
        }
        free(userinput);
        
        return (0);
}
```

link to execute() function:  https://github.com/tcrz/simple_shell/blob/dev/exec.c

Comment: Pass `size` in `get_cmd()` with pointer.  Must work together.

Comment: What is the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault. Run your program in a debugger to find that out and to further debug the problem.

Comment: most likely args[0] is NULL when you call strcmp. Also `sizeof(char)` is always 1 in C

Comment: @kaylum how do i run it with a debugger? is there a gcc option? newbie here

Comment: tony baidoo, `execute()` is not a standard library function.  Please provide documentation on its use.

Comment: takes array of args as parameter and executes args using  `execve()`

Comment: tonybaidoo,  Please provide link to `execute()` use/documentation.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica here, https://github.com/tcrz/simple_shell/blob/dev/exec.c

Comment: @bruceg ha yeah that was the problem, now handled to make sure args is never empty, that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code lied to `getline()`**

`getline()` expects a *paired* pointer to a pointer and a pointer to a size of that buffer. Instead it passed the address of a pointer and an unrelated  pointer to a magic number of 1000, but did not keep those in sync.

Instead, in `main()`

```
// char *userinput
// userinput = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1000);
size_t userinput_size = 1000; // add
char *userinput = malloc(userinput_size);


...
  // get_cmd(&userinput);
  getline(&userinput, &userinput_size, stdin);
```

---

**No overflow protection and wrong size**

```
    char **eachstr;
    //                   wrong size (sizeof a char??)
    // eachstr = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
     
    //               right size (sizeof a char*)
    eachstr = malloc(sizeof *eachptr * 100);
    
    // while (token) {
    while ((count + 1) < 100 && token) {
            eachstr[count] = token;
```

---

**Shallow copy**

`eachstr[count] = token;` only copies the pointer and `token` is not stable.  Look to `eachstr[count] = strdup(token);` to form a copy of the string.  (Later need to free it.)

---

**Use protection**

`_strcmp(args[0], "exit")` is UB when `args[0] == NULL`. [@
bruceg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69774695/simple-shell-wont-go-to-new-line-when-enter-is-pressed/69774868#comment123335471_69774695).

Unclear why code is not using `strcmp()`.

---

**Improvement: magic numbers**

Avoid magic number 100 in `malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);`.

Rather than guess 100 is enough, consider `strspn()/strcspn()` rather than `strtok()` and make 2 tokenizing passes, the first to determine the needed size.

**Improvement: Execute "exit"`?**

When `_strcmp(args[0], "exit") == 0`, I would not expect code to still call `execute()`.

---

May have other problems too.